# how to run php script in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, scripting, eclipse-pdt

I installed Eclipse PDT-all-in-one-win32-2.0.0GA  and WampServer 2.0.

I try to run as PHP Script in eclipse  but I have this error:

"The current debugger does not have any defined PHP executable."

How do I create this .exe ??

Comment: You don't "create" it. You download it from the PHP website. This is the executable that makes PHP scripts work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ok But I do not have php.exe. I only create Test.php in my project.

In order to run **.php* files, you will need PHP installed, and because you already have installed WAMP, you should be fine.

> "The current debugger does not have any defined PHP executable."

If you have installed WAMP as you said, try to look for *php.exe* on your local hard drive and then set path in Eclipse that leads to it (eg. *c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\php.exe*). Go to *Window\Preferences\PHP\PHP Executables* and add this path to the list.

Comment: I had the same problem in Aptana Studio 3, your answer solved it.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to create this .exe

In Eclipse you need to configure the debugger settings. The debugger needs to know where the php.exe file lives.

Edit: php.exe ships with the standard PHP install on windows. When you download PHP from [www.php.net](http://www.php.net) you will find the php.exe file somewhere in the directory you installed PHP in.

Hope this helps :-)