# Please set a valid PHP executable for this launch

Tags: php, eclipse

I have just started Eclipse for developing PHP.  I did the first project in the book and it went great with a bit of help from you all.

Then I opened a second project.  While trying to configure the run path (Eclipse always starts out pointing to my server's root), Somehow I got the IDE in a state that I can't get it out of.  It pops up a dialog box when I try to run the project with the title **"launch error"** and in the box it says: **"Please set a valid PHP executable for this launch"**.  I think it has something to do with the debugger which I am not using yet.  My code is very simple, in file one:

```
<?php 
   include('helloObj.php');
   $hello= new hello();

   $hello->prntMessage();
?>
```

And in file two:

```
<?php 

class Hello {
    var $message;

    function __construct() {
        $this->message= "Hello World!";
    }

    /**
      * Function that prints the value of the instance variable 
      * $message
      */
    function prntMessage() {
        echo $this->message;
    }
}

?>
```

This was copied off a tutorial on the web (and works just fine in my browser) so I don't think it is the cause.

Also, if someone could tell me the recommended way to configure PHP run paths in Eclipse, I would appreciate that too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888500/how-to-run-php-script-in-eclipse also check for run paths: Window > Preferences > PHP > PHP Executable

Comment: Some additional information:

Comment: I deleated all the comments so only the very simple code is left.  I then tried to run run->configurations and I got another dialog box: "No PHP executables defined" "No PHP executable locations are defined.  Define a PHP executable location before continuing"

Comment: Ok. I configured the PHP.exe and I got the following message: "Launch Error -- Session Terminated"  Error launching 'New_configuration" The session could not be started.  In order to generate debug information, please make sure that the debugger is properly configured as a php.ini directive."

Comment: OK got it.  How do I give you credit for giving me a good answer?

Comment: don't really need it but why not post your own answer describing how you solved it. then mark it as answered. (this is allowed by the way on StackOverflow). I'll even up vote your answer.

Comment: Well maybe not. I am getting the error back.  Well, I know it is related to the debugger so I will hunt through the documentation on the zend debugger. If someone has a good tutorial, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Do the following:

1. `Run -> Debug Configurations`
2. Chose your PHP Debugger.  I chose XDebug
3. Find your PHP executable (`php.exe`).  In XAMPP it is at `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`
4. Point to your PHP file.
5. Press debug at bottom.

The script should run.